# Bisect recursive solution to find pow(x,n)

Tags: python

I am working on an introductory recursive problem:

> [Pow(x, n) - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/powx-n/)
>
> Implement [pow(*x*, *n*)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/pow/), which calculates *x* raised to the power *n* (x^n).
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: 2.00000, 10
> Output: 1024.00000
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: 2.10000, 3
> Output: 9.26100
> ```
>
> **Example 3:**
>
> ```
> Input: 2.00000, -2
> Output: 0.25000
> Explanation: 2^-2 = 1/2^2 = 1/4 = 0.25
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>
> - -100.0 < *x* < 100.0
> - *n* is a 32-bit signed integer, within the range [−231, 231 − 1]

My Solution with bisect divide

```py
class Solution:
    def myPow(self, x: float, n: int) -> float:
        #base case
        if n == 0: return 1
        #recur case 
        else:
            half = self.myPow(x, n//2) #floor           
            if n % 2 == 0: #even                      
                return half**2
            if n % 2 != 0: #odd
                return x * (half**2)
```

When run the TestCase

```py
    def test_b(self):
        x = 2.0
        n = -2
        answer = 0.25
        check = self.solution.myPow(x, n)
        self.assertEqual(answer, check)
```

Report error:

```py
DEBUG x: 2.0, n: -1
DEBUG x: 2.0, n: -1
DEBUG x: 2.0, n: -1
.......
DEBUG x: 2.0, n: -1
DEBUG x: 2.0, n: -1
DEBUG x: 2.0, n: -1
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
```

It stops at `n=-1` and found the awkward case

```py
In [10]: -1 // 2                                                                                                              
Out[10]: -1

In [11]: -2 // 2                                                                                                              
Out[11]: -1
```

Revised and it works

```py
class Solution:
    def myPow(self, x: float, n: int) -> float:
        """
        Runtime: 36 ms, faster than 99.70%
        Memory Usage: 13.2 MB, less than 5.53%
        """
        #base case
        if n == 0: return 1
        if n == -1: return 1/x
        #recur case 
        else:
            logging.debug(f"x: {x}, n: {n}")            
            half = self.myPow(x, n//2) #floor 

            if n % 2 == 0: #even
                logging.debug(f"even: x: {x}, n: {n}, half:{half}")                            
                return half**2
            if n % 2 != 0: #odd
                logging.debug(f"odd: x: {x}, n: {n}, half:{half}")                            
                return x * (half**2)
```

However, upon reading the discussion and other submissions. I found that all other cases prefer the base case `n < 0`

A clear example:

```py
class Solution(object):
    def myPow(self, x, n):
        """
        :type x: float
        :type n: int
        :rtype: float
        """
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        if n < 0:
            return 1 /self.myPow(x, -n)
        else:
            partial = self.myPow(x, n//2)
            result = partial * partial
            if n % 2 == 1: #odd
                result *= x
            return result
```

I think it not necessary to change negative `n` to`-n`, cos `2**10 == 2**5 * 2** 5 and 2**-10== 2**-5 * 2**-5`

Since people prefer base case `n  < 0` than `n == -1`, what's the benefits?

Comment: I do not think that comparing 2 floating ones is the best option since they are imprecise, read: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101163/what-causes-floating-point-rounding-errors , There are better ways to compare as indicated in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for `"not necessary to change negative n to-n"`:
I think it is consideration of performance and precision.

- preformance: integer multiplication is faster than float
- precision: when the number is very small, may cause precision loss.

so we prefer to do pow first, then divide.